# Is there a word or phrase referring to man's increasing realization of a humble place in the universe?

Tags: expressions

The "Copernican Shift" often refers to the shift in belief from the Earth being  the center of the Universe to the Sun being the center of the Universe. As a result, it can also be used as a phrase reflecting man's increasing realization of their humble role in the universe.

There has a similar process happening to mankind itself - first we thought we were the only planet, then the only solar system, then only galaxy, then the only creature that used tools, then the creature with the most number of genes etc. etc.

Is there another word, phrase or expression that could describe this increasingly humbling trend or position?

"Mankind had again suffered a ____, discovering our humbler role in nature than previously believed."

Comment: Your question is on the verge of being closed because it does not meet  this requirement: "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see Help Center: About single word requests"    I suggest you supply a sentence with a blank into which the word or phrase you seek can be inserted.

Comment: @ab2 Sentence example added.

Answer (score 2):

The generalized **Copernican principle**.  See:

> In physical cosmology, the Copernican principle, named after Nicolaus Copernicus, is a working assumption that arises from a modified cosmological extension of Copernicus' heliocentric universe. Under the modified Copernican principle neither the Sun nor the Earth are in a central, specially favored position in the universe.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernican_principle) In some sense, it is equivalent to the mediocrity principle. More recently, the principle has been generalized to the relativistic concept that humans are not privileged observers of the universe.[2]
>   [Copernican principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copernican_principle)

Answer (score 0):

One meaning of the word "**perspective**", as defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/perspective), is

> true understanding of the relative importance of things; a sense of
>   proportion

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it referred to as *decentering*. The second example sentence below is particularly apposite.

> **decenter**
>
> 1. Displace from the center or from a central position.
>
> Example sentences
>
> *Some within these movements understand that they have to study, to know more, to decentre themselves from the culturally dominant ideology.*
>
> *Around 1915, Shapley decentered the solar system by placing it toward the periphery of our galaxy.*
>
> *I believe it was Freud who humbly suggested that the three greatest scientific revolutions were those that decentred humanity.*
>
> [[oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/decenter?q=decentre)]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is in common usage as it's specific to astronauts, but the **Overview Effect** seems to fit here.

> It refers to the experience of seeing firsthand the reality of the Earth in space, which is immediately understood to be a tiny, fragile ball of life, "hanging in the void", shielded and nourished by a paper-thin atmosphere.
>
> From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overview_effect)

I postulate humanity is impacted by scientific discovery and even imagery of our solar system and beyond in a very similar way to the overview effect, although maybe to a lesser extent.

For example, the impact the image [Earthrise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthrise) had on humanity has been spoken about a fair bit:

> The photograph Anders took is known as "Earthrise", and its taking was without doubt one of the most profound events in the history of human culture, for at this moment we truly saw ourselves from a distance for the first time; and the Earth in its surrounding dark emptiness not only seemed infinitely beautiful, it seemed infinitely fragile. This wonderful image crystallised and cemented the sense of the planet's vulnerability which Silent Spring had awoken six years earlier. Its effect was enormous, not only because it stunned and amazed us, but because it fed into a burgeoning concept – that of Spaceship Earth.
>
> [Earthrise: the image that changed our view of the planet](http://www.independent.co.uk/environment/nature/earthrise-the-image-that-changed-our-view-of-the-planet-7837041.html) -- Michael McCarthy